# HTML/Javascript save string to server

Tags: javascript, php, save, server, overwrite

I'm trying to create a button in my website that counts the clicks and saves them to a text file on the server. I managed to make everything else work like it should except sending the data to server.

I tried using PHP but that requires page refreshing and I don't want that.

**Basically I need some help on how to overwrite a server text file with a variable (without having to refresh the page)**

Is it even possible to do this without using PHP? (Page refresh everytime data is saved)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need **something** on the server. It doesn't have to be PHP.

Comment: Read about `ajax`, Every time use hits the `service`, increase the count and return it for your webpage and print it..